# My Schengen visa has my name and family name swapped

Tags: visas, schengen

I have been issued a Schengen visa but they had my name and family name swapped. On the Visa, it should be: Family name, Name but they had it for me printed as Name, Family Name. (Ex: John Deere. it should be Deere, John but I have it John, Deere). Will this cause me a problem when travelling to Europe?
I contacted the Consulate, they said it should not be a problem but they CANNOT guarantee.

Anybody has a clue?
Thanks

Comment: I would think that if the consulate cannot guarantee it is not a problem, then they should reissue the visa. Call them back and ask for it to be corrected.

Comment: Why risk being sent back?

Comment: @user56513 Perhaps the user is asking because they are traveling very soon and want to know whether to scuttle the trip or give it a shot for something that has only a very small chance of failure.

Comment: User has not returned to clarify questions. Putting on hold.